# Apply Formula To All Used Range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am getting a

> Type mismatch

error whenever I try to run this syntax.  Essentially all I want to do is apply the formula to column A of the entire used range.  What should I change so this executes as desired?

```
Dim wSheet As Worksheet: Set wSheet = Sheets("Master")
Dim lr As Long: lr = wSheet.Cells(wSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim form

form = "=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(D2),"-","")"

With w.sheet
    .Range("A2:A" & lr).FormulaR1C1 = form
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`D2` is an xlA1 sytax; not an xlR1C1 syntax. Use `RC[3]` to provide relational address to D2 or use `.Formula` with xlA1 syntax. You also need to double up quotes within a quoted string.

```
With wSheet
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    form = "=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(D2),"" - "", TEXT(,))"
    .Range("A2:A" & lr).Formula = form
    form = "=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RC[3]),"" - "", TEXT(,))"
    .Range("A2:A" & lr).FormulaR1C1 = form
End With
```

btw, `TEXT(,)` is the same as `""`.

Comment: Is there an advantage to using `TEXT(,)` instead of `""`?

Comment: You don't have to type `""""` which i find just confuses things.